# Best practices relational design

Tags: mysql

I'm creating tables in a database currently and one of the tables has a `status` column. the `status` column has 4 different statuses that it could potentially have. I've made a separate table that has `table_statuses` and links them together via id. But I'm wondering if I shouldn't just type in the varchar directly.

i.e I have

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `m_document_version_status`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `m_document_version_status` (
  `document_version_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `value` varchar(64) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

INSERT INTO `m_document_version_status` (`value`) VALUES ("wip");
INSERT INTO `m_document_version_status` (`value`) VALUES ("scheduled");
INSERT INTO `m_document_version_status` (`value`) VALUES ("current");
INSERT INTO `m_document_version_status` (`value`) VALUES ("deprecated");

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `m_document_version`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `m_document_version` (
  `document_version_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `version` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `major` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `minor` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `patch` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `document_type_id` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `created_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `launch_date` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  `deprecated_date` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

I'm wondering if I shouldn't just remove the version_status table and input the varchars directly for simplicity

Comment: Use ENUM datatype.

Comment: But remember - the value which is a string visually is numeric in storage. So avoid implicit convertions during your operations - the result may differ from one you need in.

Answer (score 1):

These look, to me, like statuses in a workflow that you are creating.
As such, it is *highly likely* that these status values will *change* over time.  Because of this, I would *discount* the use of an Enum.  Changing an Enum requires you to change the *table definition*, which requires you (as DBA) to get involved.  Adding a new status [row] into a regular table makes it very easy to add new statuses, potentially even being a part of your application and Users being able to do this for themselves!  (Obviously, you'll have a constraint that *prevents* them from deleting statuses that are in use!)

Also, I would recommend this approach over using a simple, varchar column, if only for the sake of consistency.  is it possible that someone (you?) could accidentally(?) enter a status of "WIP" instead of "wip" and what effect would that have on your application code?

Answer (score 0):

There are many pros and cons of `ENUM`.  Search this forum for debates, sometimes heated.

I'll take the pro-ENUM side for this one question...

```
status ENUM ("unk", "wip", "scheduled", "current", "deprecated") DEFAULT "unk" NOT NULL
```

Notes:

- All references to `status` use human-readable values, like `'vip'`.
- Space-efficient (1 byte).  This is better than the 4-byte `INT` you suggested.  (cf `TINYINT`)
- `WHERE` clauses are more efficient by not having to `JOIN` to the other table.  In some cases this is minor; in some cases, it makes a huge difference.
- Case folding is easily handled by specifying a collation for the column.  (Probably the default provided by the table is `..._ci` anyway.)
- If there is a 5th case where you might want to say `NULL`, or `N/A`, etc, then I recommend putting that case first in the list.  (I often use `'unk'` or `'unknown'`.
- It is subtly better to have a default value than to use `NULL`.
- Adding another status *on the end* is just a simple, *non-blocking*, `ALTER`.  If the DBA and the programmer are not on speaking terms, you have bigger problems.
- Cost of an "implicit conversion"?  As I often say - expressions are far less important to performance than the cost of fetching rows.